# JavaScript use constructor parameters in methods, which way is valid?

Tags: javascript

I have js object like this:

```
var Dog = function(dogName) {
  this.bark = function() {
    console.log(dogName + " is barking");
  }
}
```

and

```
var Dog = function(dogName) {
  this.dogName = dogName;
  this.bark = function() {
    console.log(this.dogName + " is barking");
  }
}
```

I can use both the same way:

```
var puppy = new Dog("Ringo");
puppy.bark();
```

My question is is there any practical difference between those two approaches? Is it better to assign constructor parameters to `this.<field>`, or I can just utilize those parameters straight away as they are accessible to inner functions? Are there any special cases for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is what happens when you say

```
var puppy = new Dog("Ringo");
puppy.dogName = "George";
puppy.bark();
```

With the first approach, it will still use the name "Ringo" and with the second approach it will say "George".  For the same reason if you try to say

```
var puppy = new Dog("Ringo");
console.log("created new puppy: " + puppy.dogName);
```

that will work with the second version but not the first.  So if your goal is to make `dogName` effectively private so that it can't be accessed or changed after being initialized, you should go with the first approach, otherwise always go with the second approach.

Answer (score 4):

The big difference is the parameter `dogName` is functionally scoped to what you declare inline -- it's functionally private.  Also if you change the value through an instance (like puppy) it won't change the function output.

For example, if I do:

`Dog.prototype.bark2 = function() { console.log(dogName); }`

This will fail because it's out of scope.  But adding it to `this` gives me access so I can do `console.log(this.dogName)`.  So again, it's really about scope and how you want it to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, `dogName` is private - there's no way to examine the object and find the value of that variable.  You can infer it by calling `bark`, but you can't see it directly; only code declared inside that `function` expression can see it.

In the second version, `dogName` is publically visible as `object.dogName`.